# Start android Activity after receiving sms

Tags: android

Application starts and runs as a service in background.
I want to run an Activity, after receiving specific text from any phone number

Receive SMS java class as follows,

ReceiveSMS.java

```
public class ReceiveSMS  extends BroadcastReceiver {

    Boolean SendSMS;
    String Mobileno;
    String VarMessageBody;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";
        if (bundle != null) {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                Mobileno = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                str += " :";
                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                VarMessageBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                str += "\n";
                Mobileno = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();

            }
            if (VarMessageBody.startsWith("START")) {
                Intent intentHome = new Intent(context,SimpleActivity.class);
                intentHome.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intentHome);

            }

        }



}
```

}

Simple activity class as follows

```
public class SimpleActivity extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

This is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.androidautostartup"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<receiver
android:name=".BootComplete"
android:enabled="true"
android:exported="false" >
<intent-filter android:priority="99999">
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver android:name=".ReceiveSMS">
<intent-filter android:priority="99999">
<action android:name="android.provider.telephony.SMS_RECIEVED"></action>
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:name=".AutoStartUp" >
</service>
<activity android:name="com.example.androidautostartup">   
</activity>
<activity android:name="com.example.androidautostartup.SimpleActivity">
</activity>
<activity
android:name="com.example.androidautostartup.MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

please anyone can solve this it  does't run simple activity after receiving the "START" sms message.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: it does not work,, although it supposed to run simpleactivity .class it does not run after receiving "START" sms.

Comment: debug it. run step by step, assert that you receive what you expect.

Comment: Do you really need to receive both on boot and on sms events? you don't need to be running a service to get the sms event AFAIK.

Comment: appication on boot starts service fine. so I really want to keep that service to call simpleActivity on receiving sms.

Comment: I can see that application running on the Running services on android settings. My requirement is to call simpleActivity after receiving sms containing "START" on its body.

Comment: No, no. You can always start the service *after* you receive the sms. What you're doing now will do absolutely nothing for you, except garner you all the battery blame from angry one-star reviewers for seemingly running in the background all the time (although your service will do absolutely nothing extra during that time).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the SimpleActivity to your AndroidManifest.

Comment: Even though I have added SimpleActivity as Activity problem still exists.

Comment: any help? I want to run the SimpleActivity.class after receiving sms. containing "START"

Comment: Even if you should not launch an Activity from a BroadcastReceiver (you should put a Notification that launch the Activity when it's clicked), your code should work. There's something of strange inside your for loop: for example the variable VarMessageBody contains only the last message text. Is this what you want? Have you tried to add a breakpoint just before the startActivity() ?